# Centripetal force problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

Can someone please help me with this problem , I need an explanation not a solution to this problem.

Ok so this task says: Car is driving with constant speed on on circular inclined twisted road. on the picture is shown the back of the car. which is the direction of the net force on the car? I saw that the answer is C but i dont get it why if centripetal force is alway pointed towards the center I know that D and A cant

[image]

be the answer because D is force of riction and A is the force of the car that acts on the car but i really dont get why is the direction of force pointed that way.Thank you!

  1.

Comment: If you don't think it is C, which direction do you think it is? Where do you think the centre of the circular motion is?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: If you want your object to be simply rotating about the centre it must have net force that points in the direction of the centre. If you would pick answer D instead of C, it would mean that you could resolve net force into cetripetal one and perpebdicular to cebtripetal one. And so the car would not only move in a circle but also would accelerate downwards.